# Python Decryption issue with Cryptography Library

Tags: python

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    import os
    with open("mykey.key", "rb") as file:
        key0 = file.read()
    key = Fernet(key0)

    dir = "C:\\Users\\botta\\Desktop\\Harmless Folder"
    for i in os.listdir(dir):
    with open(i, "rb") as f:
        decryption = key.decrypt(f)
        decrypted = f.read()
        print(decrypted.decode())
```

Here is my code for decrypting files that have been encrypted within a folder on my desktop. The issue is this error:

```
c:/Users/botta/Desktop/Code/decrypt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\botta\Desktop\Code\decrypt.py", line 15, in <module>
    decryption = key.decrypt(f)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\botta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 84, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\botta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 110, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise TypeError("token must be bytes or str")
TypeError: token must be bytes or str
```

I have no idea what the error means.

I expected the code to decrypt the encrypted files in a folder in my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the file, would you try reading it with 'r' instead of 'rb' and then use the encode function?

```
with open("mykey.key", "r") as file:
    key0 = file.read()
    # when encode key need
    # key0 = key0.encode('utf-8')
key = Fernet(key0)


for i in os.listdir(dir):
    with open(i, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read().encode('utf-8')
        decryption = key.decrypt(data)
        decrypted = f.read()
        print(decrypted.decode())
```